# Excel Crashes when trying to run powershell command

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I am having an issue trying to run a complex HTTP Request through a powershell command from a VBA function.

VBA Code Below: The powershell script runs fine from inside powershell

```
Public Function PS_GetOutput(id As String) As String
    'Setup the powershell command properly
    psCommand = "powershell -command " & "C:\Users\promney\temp1\curlCommand.ps1 " & id
    'Execute the command
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run psCommand, 3, True
    'Get an instance of the clipboard to capture the save value
End Function
```

The PS1 file should grab the html and put a string on the clipboard. Instead, the PS window opens as a blue field, then it and excel crash completely and immediately. What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I would include the PS script but that is a lot of possibly sensitive info to scrub and I'm pretty sure the issue is in the VBA, since it works fine unless called from excel.